# Railscast 198, but using formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, formtastic

How could you do what's covered in [RyanB's Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/198-edit-multiple-individually?view=comments) on editing multiple records individually, using Formtastic? Formtastic doesn't use form_tag, which RyanB's method relies on.

Comment: You can still use the normal form helpers within the formtastic form.

Comment: Not form_tag, according to Justin French: [link](http://groups.google.com/group/formtastic/browse_thread/thread/887f476fcc901eef)  "Formtastic can't be used with form_tag."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `semantic_form_for` is just a wrapper around `form_for` so you can use the same parameters. Here is a formtastic version of [Ryan Bates' screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/198-edit-multiple-individually)

`views/products/edit_individual.html.erb`

```
<% semantic_form_for :update_individual_products, :url => update_individual_products_path, :method => :put do |f| %>
  <% for product in @products %>
    <% f.fields_for "products[]", product do |ff| %>
      <h2><%=h product.name %></h2>
      <%= render "fields", :f => ff %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= submit_tag "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

`views/products/index.html.erb`

```
<% semantic_form_for :edit_individual_products, :url => edit_individual_products_path do %>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  <% for product in @products %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= check_box_tag "product_ids[]", product.id %></td>
      <td><%=h product.name %></td>
      <td><%=h product.category.name %></td>
      <td><%= number_to_currency product.price %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_product_path(product) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Destroy", product, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </table>
  <p>
    <%= select_tag :field, options_for_select([["All Fields", ""], ["Name", "name"], ["Price", "price"], ["Category", "category_id"], ["Discontinued", "discontinued"]]) %>
    <%= submit_tag "Edit Checked" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Please note that you can use the `form_for` helpers as well in `formtastic`.

**Update**

If you like to use nested attributes as well it should work out of the box, using fields_for on the form partial. Lets stick with the railscast example and say that:

product.rb

```
has_many :commments
accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
```

You can edit the comments on the _fields.html.erb of the products like:

```
<%= f.fields_for :comments do |cf| %>
  <%=render 'comments/fields', :f=>cf%>
<%end%>
```

And make sure you have a fields partial in your comments views.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I applied this to Ryan's other tutorial on editing multiple, and to update the edit_multiple view to rails 3 I had to manually state the path to the non-restful controller action and method, like this: 

`= semantic_form_for :isbn, :url => {:controller => 'isbns', :action => 'update_multiple'}, :html=>{:method=>:put} do |f|`

Now if I can just get it to work with accepts_nested_attributes_for, I'm laughing...

Comment: Updated my answer to show you how to use it with nested attributes.

Comment: How kind of you! Except, humph, I can't get it to work. Can I prevail upon you to glance at my code on this new question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623389/accepts-nested-attribute-for-and-multiple-edits). I do appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi @dombesz , Can you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26456913/rails4-formtastic3-0-save-multiple-instances-for-answer-models-at-the-same . I think I have a similar problem with Q&A model and I think you might have some pointers for me. Thanks already.